# Coin Toss Monte Calro Simulating Exact Heads

Tags: r, probability, montecarlo

I'm trying to write a function for an unfair coin toss with four inputs: the weight/probability of getting heads, the number of simulations, the number of flips per sim, and the exact number of heads I want to find the probability of acquiring.

The function below returns errors I don't understand for the flipping part:

In if (percent_heads == nheads) counter <- counter + 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 50

```
counter = 0
percent_heads = NULL
flip_function <- function(p, nheads, nflips, nsim){
  for(i in 1:nsim){
    flips <- sample(c("H","T"), size = nflips, replace = TRUE, prob = c(p, 1-p))
    percent_heads[i] <- length(which(flips == "H")) / nflips
    if(percent_heads == nheads) counter <- counter + 1
    }
  return(counter/nsim)
}
```

Comment: Ok, I realized what the error meant. So I changed it to read:

if(percent_heads[i] == nheads) counter = counter + 1



However, the function just returns 0 every time, even when i enter (1, 100, 100, 10000)

Comment: your `percent_heads` is the proportion while `nheads` is # of heads, thus they won't equal normally, will they?

Comment: Indeed! I realized that like a minute longer looking at it. I'm a fool. I posted my new function below. If possible, I would greatly appreciate someone checking it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm an idiot. After a little more deliberation, I believe I got it to work. Could someone smarter than me please verify this works as intended:

```
counter = 0
total_heads = NULL
flip_function <- function(p, nheads, nflips, nsim){
for(i in 1:nsim){
flips <- sample(c("H","T"), size = nflips, replace = TRUE, prob = c(p, 1-p))
total_heads[i] <- length(which(flips == "H"))
if(total_heads[i] == nheads) counter <- counter + 1
}
return(counter/nsim)
}
```

Comment: It is good roughly. Better to reset `counter` within your first line of the function (`counter = 0`). You may compare with theoretical results `choose(nflips, nheads)*p^(nheads)*(1-p)^(nflips - nheads)`